# Variables in a tag - Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

What is the best practice when I want to put variable in the string of a tag in Freemarker ?

For example, I want to post a different picture in my webpage for different items. All of the pictures have different names that related to the name of the item.

I want to be able to do something like this. This doesn't work, but is there something similar that could work ?

```
<img src="/images/" + ${item.name}+ ".jpg">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img src="/images/${item.name}.jpg">
```

when you have `${}` you use it directly in html

Comment: Thank you, the first one worked ! The second example didn't because the _src_ tag didn't recognize the entire string. It only recognized the "/images/" part and not the rest.

Comment: Right, the second method was freemarker concatenation, I removed it so no one else gets confused